# How to work with jQuery AJAX and PHP array return

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have a jquery ajax request like;

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'processor.php',
    data: 'data1=testdata1&data2=testdata2&data3=testdata3',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      if(result){
        alert(result);
      }else{
        alert("error");
      }
    }
});
```

The handler `processor.php` is set to return an array like;

```
$array = array("a","b","c","d");
echo $array;
```

I want to do action in client side based on this. Say if array[0] is 'b', I want to alert "hi". Again if array[2] is 'x', I want to alert "hello", and so on. How can I filter array elements in order to grab their data?

Answer (score 25):

You will have to return the array encoded in the json form like following

```
$array = array("a","b","c","d");
echo json_encode($array);
```

then you can access it in javascript converting it back to an array/object like

```
var result = eval(retuned_value);
```

You can also navigate through all array elements using a for loop

```
for (var index in result){
    // you can show both index and value to know how the array is indexed in javascript (but it should be the same way it was in the php script)
    alert("index:" + index + "\n value" + result[index]);
}
```

---

in your code it should look something like:

#### PHP Code:

```
$array = array("a","b","c","d");
echo json_encode( $array );
```

#### jQuery script

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'processor.php',
    data: 'data1=testdata1&data2=testdata2&data3=testdata3',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      if(result){
        resultObj = eval (result);
        alert( resultObj );
      }else{
        alert("error");
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: -1 No need to use `eval`.

Comment: i got it worked with eval but not worked without eval. also my php script didnt set to any specific header like HMR says on below answer.

Answer (score 2):

Return JSON from php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

and in javascript create an object from the json string, you can do this with using getJSON instead of ajax
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Make sure your php sets the right response header:

```
 header ("content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

I find the best way  to return an array from php to Ajax (jscript):

on the php side: `echo json_encode($myArray);`
on the javascript side (e.g. `myAjax.responseText`)
`replyVal = JSON.parse(myAjax.responseText);`

To send arrays TO php from javascript, use the matching `JSON.stringify()` to send
and php `json_decode()` to receive

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP code encode the array as JSON object

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Then you need to convert the JSON object into a Javascript/jQuery-compatible object. Afterwards you can convert back to an array

```
$.ajax({
      success: function(result) {

      jq_json_obj = $.parseJSON(result); //Convert the JSON object to jQuery-compatible

      if(typeof jq_json_obj == 'object'){ //Test if variable is a [JSON] object
        jq_obj = eval (jq_json_obj); 

        //Convert back to an array
        jq_array = [];
        for(elem in jq_obj){
            jq_array.push(jq_obj[elem]);
        }
        console.log(jq_array);
      }else{
        console.log("Error occurred!"); 
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'processor.php',//please return in json  
    dataType : 'json',//to get data in json   
    data: 'data1=testdata1&data2=testdata2&data3=testdata3',  
    cache: false,  
    success: function(result) {  
      if(result.array.length > 0){  
        for(var i=0;i<result.array.length;i++){  
            if(result.array.[i]== 'a'){  
               //do somthing..  
               //here, you can use switch case too...  
            }  
        }  
      }  
    }  
});
```