# Ajax - returned json object is null in ie

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Hi I have a javascript code that connects to a php script via ajax. This php script returns an array. In the success function of the ajax call, I use the returned array to display information to the user. This all works fine in all the browsers I have tried except Internet Explorer. I get the following error:

```
Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference
```

'0' is the index of the first element in the array. Here is the code:

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/add.php",
    data: 'id=' + itemid,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = data[0];
        document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = data[1];
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = data[2];
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

PHP

```
$output = array();
$output[0] = $itemname;
$output[1] = $itemdescription;
$output[2] = $itemprice;
echo json_encode($output);
exit();
```

I tried `console.log(data)` in the success function and in Internet Explorer it returns null whereas other browsers it returns the array. Does anyone know what is wrong here?

The error code on the console in IE is SCRIPT5007. Upon searching this, this means:

```
You attempted to invoke the Object.prototype.toString or Object.prototype.valueOf method on an object of a type other than Object. The object of this type of invocation must be of type Object.
```

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-GB&k=k(VS.WebClient.Help.SCRIPT5007)

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps try putting `data = JSON.parse(data)` at the beginning of the success function - ?

Comment: @rm-vanda the dataType is json so that wouldnt be required. However I still tried that and it returns null

Comment: What does the server response look like in IE in dev tools?

Comment: Can you try alert (typeof data) and alert (data.length) and tell us what you've got?

Comment: @LShetty the typeof is object and the length returns the following: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @CBroe The response is HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the issue with your sample code.  I have tested your code on both Safari and IE 11.

Here is the sample code I used (modified from yours):

**PHP Code Sample**

```
<?php
$output = array();
$output[0] = 'Name';
$output[1] = 'Description for Item: ' . $_POST['id'];
$output[2] = 'Price';
echo json_encode($output);
exit();
?>
```

Since I do not know what $itemname, $itemdescription or $itemprice is, I hard coded in values except for the passed in id.

**HTML Code Sample**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="name"></div>
        <div id="desc"></div>
        <div id="price"></div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var $Xhr = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./add.php",
                data: {
                    id: 1
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {},
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
            $Xhr.done(function renderData(data){
                document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = data[0];
                document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = data[1];
                document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = data[2];
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Notes:** 
 - I use './' in the Ajax URL due to the location of my sample 'add.php' file.
 - I used an object for data instead of string. This is how I normally build the data variable.
 - An alternative to success, I tried using the $.done and was able to still retrieve data.

**Output:**

> Name
> Description for Item: 1
> Price

Try using the $.done method and see if this helps you.
https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

I would also recommend monitoring the network in developer tools to validate the request and response.

Comment: I get the error that done isnt a function of $Xhr. Also my server response is HTTP/1.1 200 OK when doing my original way

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.4.4

Comment: Alright, that is why done isn't a function of $Xhr.  That method was introduced/added in jQuery version 1.5.  In the meantime let me downgrade my jQuery version to see if I can now reproduce the issue.  You could also upgrade jQuery in the meantime to see if that solves the issue.  If that is a possible option for you.

Comment: I will upgrade and see what happens

Comment: When I upgraded and tried your code, I get an error alert saying Syntax Error

Comment: I am still unable to reproduce issue.  I have uploaded a working copy to JSFiddle.  I made an additional change  to mock the server response.  I use JSFiddle's Ajax URL to return what add.php would return, also there is a three second delay for the data to be returned.  http://jsfiddle.net/4a74T/

Comment: The reason your jsfiddle code doesnt show an error is because you are mimicking the server output. After doing extensive debugging, the problem is the post data that is sent in the ajax call. It is null so when the server reads the post values and does whatever it has to do, it is working with null variables so in the ajax success or done function it is returning null, when infact those post variables have actual data.

Comment: Its weird because when I change use GET instead of POST, it works fine. So I think I may need to just do that. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Ahh, so the problem is now solved correct?  With the given code sample, I was expecting the ajax data to contain an id and that data would be returned back.

Answer (score 0):

source: [How to work with jQuery AJAX and PHP array return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311320/how-to-work-with-jquery-ajax-and-php-array-return)

This link mentions running eval on the returned data to turn it into an object.
So, maybe try:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/add.php",
data: 'id=' + itemid,
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
    var success_data = eval (data);
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = success_data[0];
    document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = success_data[1];
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = success_data[2];
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
}
```

});

Just an idea, sorry I can't test this right now.

Comment: I get the same problem in IE. This code works in Firefox though

Comment: hm, ok, so another idea is this. I looked at my own ajax code using POST (I saw that you mentioned that might be a problem elsewhere) and the only difference I see is you are passing type before url. When I checked the documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  it looks like url should be sent before settings if you are going to send it. This is the only difference between your AJAX request using POST and mine so it's worth a shot.