# Update DOM with jQuery ajax array results

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have search results generated by a 3rd party script that I would like to add data to. I have parsed the results to get an array of id's, and queried the database for additional fields. The ajax success method receives the formatted array back, but now I'm stuck on how to get those results into the right place in the DOM.

The HTML:

```
    <div class="ihf-results-property-info">
        <div class="ihf-results-price">LIST: $2,150,000</div>
        <div class="ihf-results-links"> <a href="#"> 24 Photos </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ihf-results-extra-info">
        <div class="ihf-results-listingnum hidden-xs">Listing # 727938</div>
    </div>
    Repeat...
```

The last div I included in the example has the unique ID I'm using for the query. I'd like to use that to associate the ajax return with proper placement in the DOM. Here is my javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //  grab the listings numbers so we can query the db for extra data
    var listings = $('.ihf-results-listingnum').map(function() {

        // grab just the digits
        var listingNum = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

        // add the listing number to the parent so we can target it later
        $( this ).parents('.ihf-results-extra-info').parent().addClass('marketing-details-' + listingNum);

        return listingNum;

    // use .get to create  an array of the listing numbers
    }).get();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "custom/07-idx-queries.php",
        data: 'mlsNums=' + listings, // looks like ?mlsNums=735383,727468,699876...
        success: function(result) {
            // this logic came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311320/how-to-work-with-jquery-ajax-and-php-array-return
            resultJson = $.parseJSON(result); 
            if (typeof resultJson == 'object') {
                jsObject = eval(resultJson);

                jsArray = [];
                for(elem in jsObject){
                    jsArray.push(jsObject[elem]);
                }
                console.log(jsArray);
                // this works as expected, except keys are 0 based

                // This is where it all falls apart. I want to extract each object and stick it in the DOM in the correct place
                jQuery.each(jsArray, function(key, value) {
                    $( this ).appendTo('.marketing-details-' + key);
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log("error occurred");
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    })
});
```

And the php I'm using produces the desired results from the db, with the exception that it is a numerical array. I think an associative array would work better when trying to put the results into the DOM, tha way I could use the ID's as the key and match them to the classes I added. Here is the relevant code from custom/07-idx-queries.php:

```
$mls_nums = explode(",",$_GET['mlsNums']);
// removed all of the conditionals to keep the question clean
$html = array();

    foreach ($mls_nums as $mls_num) {
        // just retreiving a single object from each row for now
        $remarks = $mysqli->query("SELECT mr FROM listings WHERE ln = '$mls_num'")->fetch_object()->mr;

        // format the data
        $my_html = "<p class='marketing-remarks mlsnum-".$mls_num."'>$remarks</p>";

        // build an array of the results - necessary?
        array_push($html,$my_html);
    }

    // send the data back in a JSON string
    echo json_encode($html);
```

So my goal is to query the db for up to 10 rows, and insert the results into an equal number of new divs that are children to a div with the same id number in its class. I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you should only paste the minimal code related to your problem. If the issue is ajax related, paste that part.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP do this:

```
$html[$mls_num] = $my_html;
// this isn't needed
// array_push($html,$my_html);
```

Now your returned data has a way to tie into the target div.

Not clear if you have control over the HTML in the first part of your example, but this would be one approach.

```
<div class="ihf-results-listingnum hidden-xs">Listing # 727938</div>
<div class="remarks" id="remarks_<?= $listingid; ?>"></div>
```

Then in the JavaScript `$("#remarks_" + key).html(value);`

Otherwise, you need to use jQuery to locate the div with the listing id using the [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
$("div:contains('# " + key + "')").appendTo(value);
```

'# " + key + "' would equate to # 1234 or whatever it is. This won't work if the same listing is on the page twice though!

Comment: After changing my php code to match your example, and adding `console.log(key + ": : + value);` inside my jQuery.each() function, I still see numerical keys (zero based). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Oops... jQuery's each function is `function( index, value )`, so try doing console.log(value) and see what that reveals.

Comment: I tried that too, same result. I think the jsArray conversion may be unnecessary. I just replaced jsArray with jsObject in the .each loop and now the 6-digit keys are showing up. I'm troubleshooting that now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is the working success method. Thanks to LG_PDX for the cleaned up php. I eliminated the unnecessary processing as `.each()` appears to iterate just fine over the JSON response:

```
            success: function(result) {
            resultJson = $.parseJSON(result);
            if (typeof resultJson == 'object') {

                $.each(resultJson, function(key, value) {
                    $('.marketing-details-' + key).append( value );
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
```